# Select buttons more than one kotlin and using variables in findViewById() - android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, element

I want to do actions with 9 buttons.Is there anyway to do action with 9 buttons in one time,not one by one.
If I could add variable to findViewById() I would solve problem.
For example I want to select 9 button at once(with `for` loop) like below

```
for(i in 1..9){
   findViewById(R.id.button+i).text="New Text"
}
```

This way not working,please suggest optimal ways.

I want like this in javascript equivalent:
`document.getElementById("button"+i)`

Comment: What do you mean *in one time*? Clarify by editing your question.

Comment: @mTak, I edited question. Think that there are 100 button and I should change all of them,should I call buttons one by one?

Comment: see my edited answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declare this in your activity:

```
var buttons: ArrayList<Button> = arrayListOf()
```

and in onCreate():

```
    for (i in 1..100) {
        buttons.add(findViewById<Button>(resources.getIdentifier("button" + i, "id", this.getPackageName())))
    }
```

Now you have all your buttons in a list.

if you want to change the state of your buttons, say disable them all:

```
buttons.forEach { it.isEnabled = false }
```

Comment: Im new to android studio,java and kotlin. Can you clarify this method?

Comment: This works if all the buttons have names like button1, button2,.... See my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

You can set tag for each button (like button1, button2, etc.) and do something like this

```
for(i in 1..9){
   (view.findViewWithTag("button"+i.toString()) as Button).text = "New Text"
}
```

Comment: did you set use setTag() method on your buttons? what exception you're getting?